# Redirect back to a page with field values submitted earlier

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this sign-in page...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>  
<form action="signin_process.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<br />
SID: <input type="text" name="sid">
<br />
Nick Name: <input type="text" name="nn">
<br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<br />
Password: <input type="text" name="pw">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The signin_process.php file...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Signin_process</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$sid = $_POST['sid'];
$nn = $_POST['nn'];
$em = $_POST['email'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE SID='$sid'") or die('Query failed');
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Invalied SID')
    window.location.href='welcome.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
    }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE nickname='$nn'") or die('Query failed');
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Nickname Takken!')
    window.location.href='welcome.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
    }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE email='$em'") or die('Query failed');
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Email already in use!')
    window.location.href='welcome.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if SID, Nick name or email is not valid, i want to redirect to the sign-in page and the field values will be there which were given earlier. So that in don't have to input all the values all over again. Like we see in many sites, we just had to change the input that was not excepted and submit again.

Thanks!

Comment: So, just set the value attribute of the input fields?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question! you have to elaborate a little more sir!

Comment: Simply store the submitted values in session. If the validation fails, display them as default values of all input fields.

Comment: can you write some code for this? plz... @kajetons

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
if ($_POST['name'] == '') {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.history.back();</script>";
}
```

By this way field values will be there which were given earlier.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example:

Your login form:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php 
                $errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) && is_array($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
                foreach ($errors as $error):
            ?>
            <li><?php print $error; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <form action="signin_process.php" method="post">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php print !isset($_SESSION['name']) ?: $_SESSION['name']; ?>" />
            <label for="sid">SID: </label>
            <input type="text" id="sid" name="sid" value="<?php print !isset($_SESSION['sid']) ?: $_SESSION['sid']; ?>" />
            <label for="nn">Nick Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="nn" name="nn" value="<?php print !isset($_SESSION['nn']) ?: $_SESSION['nn']; ?>" />
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php print !isset($_SESSION['email']) ?: $_SESSION['email']; ?>" />
            <label for="pw">Password: </label>
            <input type="text" id="pw" name="pw" value="<?php print !isset($_SESSION['pw']) ?: $_SESSION['pw']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Your PHP form submission:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ("connection.php");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $name = $_SESSION['name'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
        $sid = $_SESSION['sid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sid']);
        $nn = $_SESSION['nn'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['nn']);
        $em = $_SESSION['email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $pw = $_SESSION['pw'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pw']);

        $_SESSION['errors'] = [];

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE SID='$sid'") or die('Query failed');
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
             $_SESSION['errors'][] = 'Invalid SID.';
             header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
             exit();
         }

         $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE nickname='$nn'") or die('Query failed');
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
             $_SESSION['errors'][] = 'Nickname already in use.';
             header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
             exit();
         }

         $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE email='$em'") or die('Query failed');
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
             $_SESSION['errors'][] = 'E-mail already in use.';
             header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
             exit();
         }
    }

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
?>
```

That should work.

P.S. You should look into prepared statements and input filtering. Safety should always come first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['nam']) && (isset($_POST['sid']) && (isset($_POST['nn'])){

    if(($_POST['name']=== 'user')&& ($_POST['sid']==='sid')&&($_POST['nn']==='sid')){
        echo "correct";

            $_SESSION['us'] = "YES";
            $_SESSION['sid'] = "YES";
            $_SESSION['nn'] = "YES";
            header("location: userpage.php"); //directs to user area
    }else {
        echo "Wronge Password/Name/Nickname";
            $_SESSION['us'] = $_POST['name'];
            $_SESSION['sid'] = $_POST['sid'];
            $_SESSION['nn'] = $_POST['nn'];
            header("location: userpage.php"); //userpage redirects to this page 
    }}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>  
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['us']) ? $_SESSION['us'] : ""; ?> >
<br />
SID: <input type="text" name="sid" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['sid']) ? $_SESSION['sid'] : ""; ?> >
<br />
Nick Name: <input type="text" name="nn" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['sid']) ? $_SESSION['sid'] : ""; ?> >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```